# How can I update an association (has_one) in a Rails AR using link_to_remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to-remote

This is what I have in my view:

```
  <%= link_to_remote "Responded - Positive",
      :url => contact_path(@contact, :status => 'positive response'),
      :update => "status" %>
```

This is what I have as a route:

```
  map.resources :contacts, :has_one => :status_contact
```

Here is what I used in my controller:

```
  def create
    @status_contact = StatusContact.new(params[:status_contact])
    if @status_contact.save
      #flash[:notice] = "Successfully created status contact."
      #redirect_to @status_contact
      render :text => "Set status to #{@status_contact.status}."
    else
      render :text => "bomb"
    end
  end
```

My desired outcome is that for the specific Contact, it will update the attribute Contact.status with the value 'positive response' and do so via ajax.

Right now, I am getting a 404 error.  What do I need to do to correct this?

This is the error that I am still getting:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/contacts/24?method=put&status=positive+response 404 Not Found
    312ms
```

Comment: Asking a lot of questions today, are we not? ;]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably sending your request with the wrong verb (:post instead of :put). Which action of your controller are you trying to reach? It's probably the update action… Try to modify your link by specifying the :put method:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Responded - Positive", :url => contact_path(@contact, :status => 'positive response'), :method => :put, :update => "status" %>
```

Comment: cool, will try that -- does it change anything if it is an "association?"  Meaning contact belongs_to a status_contact table?

Comment: thanks -- it's odd -- I didn't have this problem before I changed teh associations.....I will try this...